# Assessing the Validity of Conclusions Based on Limited Findings

Tags: sample-size, bias, small-sample, uncertainty, research-design

*Introduction*: Archaeological research often involves drawing conclusions about past societies and cultures based on a limited number of artifacts or findings. In some cases, such as the study of synagogues in the Levant, the number of findings may be significantly smaller than the number that existed during the period of interest (0.1%, 1%, 10%). This raises questions about the validity of conclusions based on small sample size and the role of statistical analysis in assessing confidence and significance.

*Questions:*

1. What minimum sample size is required to draw valid conclusions in archaeological research, particularly when studying the prevalence or frequency of artifacts such as synagogues in a given region and time period?
2. How can statistical methods be used to account for bias and uncertainty in archaeological data, such as the incomplete or limited nature of findings, to arrive at more reliable conclusions about past societies and cultures?
3. What assumptions can be made about the size of the population and distribution of synagogues, and how can statistical analysis be used to assess the level of confidence and significance of conclusions drawn from a small sample size of artifacts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A major issue here is that, as you mention in item 2, the samples you have may very well not be random samples as assumed by standard statistical inference; you may see certain things with systematically larger probability than others, and you may not know about these probabilities.

This means, unfortunately, that not only may standard inference be misleading, but also you can't really know how misleading it is.

All statistical inference is based on model assumptions, and any recommendation of required sample sizes (item 1) will also be based on such assumptions, which means that such recommendations cannot be made for situations where these assumptions don't hold. An arbitrarily large sample size can be systematically biased in ways you cannot see.

I think that probably the best that can be done is to use all available subject matter knowledge to model possible processes that led to the data you observe. Such models may depend on parameters for which you have to assume certain values and that you cannot estimate from data (such as how systematically different the things are that you ultimately observe from those that had originally been there). You can then generate artificial data from such model, apply inference as you would to real data, and see how this relates to the "truth" that you have put into the model. Doing this with various different parameter choices can give you an idea of how much variation and uncertainty there is.

Such modeling can also be used in a Bayesian analysis where such work would be put into setting up a prior distribution that quantifies your prior beliefs about not only what's true but also how the observed data relate to it.

Doing this in practice of course requires work and knowledge of all kinds of information that is not available on this board. E.g., "What assumptions can be made about the size of the population and distribution of synagogues" - that's not really for the statisticians to know, rather the subject matter specialists need to decide this (maybe with statistician's help "translating" the information into a formal distribution).